# Intellij idea cant access to starter class of Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, intellij-idea

my class of spring boot start located in an external jar.This external jar is a dependency for this project.When I try to create a configuration of Spring Boot in IntelliJ, it saying that it cannot access this class.
I added in pom.xml a tag of the main class, and running it through plugin of maven Spring Boot, and everything work, but its annoying, because every change I need to run install.When I open the jar via dependency window in IntelliJ, I can see this class and have an option of run , and if you press run IntelliJ says cannot find spring boot class to run.

Answer (score 0):

Check: Project Settings | Maven | Importing | Import Maven projects automatically.

Plus, in the maven tab, you can add external projects as direct dependency (the green '+' button). There you have to select your project that you also added as pom.xml

Then you only have to run `mvn install` on the external project if you want to build the jar/war for your impl project. But within the IDE not need to execute installs.

Answer (score 0):

In new version you have check box of include provided dependices.Check it and will work